# Unable to install Ruby 2.7.4

Tags: ios, react-native

i am trying to run react-native iOS but when i'm opening vs code getting an error
Required ruby-2.7.4 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.7.4"'

i have system configuration

```
OS - macOS Monterey
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
Processor - 2.5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
Graphics - AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2 GB
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
```

when i'm installing ruby getting below error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to try with with "rbenv". RVM can be quite troublesome sometimes.

Installs with rbenv with brew:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

Configure your shell:

```
# run this and follow the printed instructions:
rbenv init
```

Install the Ruby version you want:

```
rbenv install 2.7.4
```

Set the Ruby version

```
rbenv global 3.1.2   # set the default Ruby version for this machine
# or:
rbenv local 3.1.2    # set the Ruby version for this directory
```

Answer (score 0):

- The error message you provided suggests that there's an issue with the installation of the ffi gem, which is required by Ruby.
- First, make sure that you have the latest version of Xcode and the Command Line Tools installed. You can install them by running the following commands in your terminal:

  ```
  xcode-select --install
  xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
  ```
- Next,try installing the ffi gem manually by running the following command:

  ```
  sudo gem install ffi -v 1.13.1 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
  ```
- Recognition Issue with Cocoapods Gem on M1 Mac : https://copyprogramming.com/howto/cocoapods-gem-not-being-properly-recognized-on-m1-mac